# My cloneFolderHTML is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an error like this.

> ReferenceError: cloneFolderHTML is not defined

```
    initialCopy.push({
        clonefolder: cloneFolderHTML
      });
```

This made me unable to access the elements, and I had to reload the page so the code could work.
I just know when opening the console and it turns `cloneFolderHTML` not defined.

how to be able to call it outside the `submitButton` function?

---

**jQuery :**

```
$('.submitButton').click(function() {
  function copyFolderList(cloneFoldername) {
    var cloneFolder = /** HTMLCODE **/;
    return cloneFolder;
  }

  if ( /* code */ ) {
    // some code
  } else {
    var cloneFolder = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("copyList"));
    if (cloneFolder == null) {
      cloneFolder = [];
    }
    let cloneFolderHTML = copyFolderList(inputan);
    cloneFolder.push({
      clonefolder: cloneFolderHTML
    });
    localStorage.setItem("copyList", JSON.stringify(cloneFolder));
    $("#navcopyrow").append(cloneFolderHTML);
  }
}); // submitButton function


var cloneFolder = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("copyList"));
if (cloneFolder != null) {
  //get the nav reference in DOM
  let navcopy = $("#navcopyrow");

  //clear the html contents
  navcopy.html('');

  for (var i = 0; i < cloneFolder.length; i++) {
    var copyitem = cloneFolder[i];
    $("#navcopyrow").append(copyitem.clonefolder);
  }
} else {
  let initialCopy = [];
  initialCopy.push({
    clonefolder: cloneFolderHTML
  });
  localStorage.setItem("copyList", JSON.stringify(initialCopy));
}
```

*Can I call `cloneFolderHTML` outside the `submitButton` function?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let cloneFolderHTML
```

`let` is an ECMAScript 6 reserved word that makes a variable block scoped.  Meaning it will only exist within the scope of it's immediately encapsulated `{}`.  Since the variable is in the `{}` of an else, it will only exist inside that else block.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: Why i can't select the element in the first time? i need reload it in order to select the element.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: ok, what should i do with `let cloneFolderHTML`? i change it to `var` ?

Comment: That is one option.  `var` is not block scoped.